# Rails 4.2 Disable before_create for seeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to disable before_create for seed files in Rails? I don't need to run my before_create method when importing data. If it makes a difference I'm using sprig gem for imports.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `skip_callback` like following:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :skip_some_callbacks

  before_create :do_something
  after_create :do_something_else

  skip_callback :create, :before, :do_something, if: :skip_some_callbacks
  skip_callback :create, :after, :do_something_else, if: :skip_some_callbacks
end
```

if you are creating active record models then you can replace your create like this:

```
person = Person.new(person_params)
person.skip_some_callbacks = true
person.save
```

if you are using factory girl at your seed than, probably it would look like something like following:

```
100.times do
    FactoryGirl.create(:person, :skip_some_callbacks => "1")
end
```

Comment: Hmm... Thank you. That give me some idea how to approach the issue. I'm still not sure how to use it with sprig but gives me something to explore :-)